# How to get data from API with DIO package- Api data Authorization with userAccessToken

Tags: flutter, api, dio

I am trying to get from an API to get user data by accessToken. I don't know How to get data that authorize with AccessToken.

when the user is not logged in the app, they don't get any data from API (**because API integrates with accessToken**)

[image]

When I am logged in to the app, then I found a token

[image]

When logged into the app, then I found the data

[image]

How can I show the data from API?

This is my UserDataController:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class UserDataController extends GetxController {
  final _dio = Dio();
  final customerDataList = RxMap();

  getuserData({String? id}) async {
    try {
      final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final value = sharedPreferences.setString('accessToken', '');

      final res = await _dio.get(
        'http://support.nbox.live:82/data/care_api/v1/$id',
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $value',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        ),
      );
      print('-----------------------');
      print(value);
      print('-----------------------');

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        print(res.data['data']['customer_info']);

        customerDataList.value = res.data['data']['customer_info'];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

And, This is my LoginController:

```
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:isp_app/src/configs/appColors.dart';
 
import 'package:isp_app/src/pages/homePage.dart';
import 'package:isp_app/src/pages/loginPage.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class LoginController extends GetxController {
  final _dio = Dio();

  //
  final username = RxString('');
  final password = RxString('');

  //
  getLoginUser() async {
    try {
      final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      final value = sharedPreferences.get('accessToken');

      final res = await _dio.post(
        'http://support.nbox.live:82/login/',
        data: {
          'username': username.value,
          'password': password.value,
        },
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer $value',
            // 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        ),
      );

      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        Get.snackbar(
          'Success',
          'Login Success',
        );

        currentUserToken(accessToken: res.data['token']);

        await Get.offAll(HomePage());
      }
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);

      Get.snackbar(
        'Error',
        'User not found',
        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        colorText: white,
      );
    }
  }

  Future<String?> currentUserToken({
    required String accessToken,
  }) async {
    final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await sharedPreferences.setString(
      'accessToken',
      accessToken,
    );

    if (accessToken.isNotEmpty) {
      Get.offAll(HomePage());
    }
    print('Current user access token is $accessToken');
  }

  userSignOut({required String accessToken}) async {
    final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    sharedPreferences.remove(accessToken);
    print('signout');
    Get.to(LoginPage());
  }
}
```

How to get the data and show the data into the app?

I am storing the token in **SharedPreferences**

For Postman Testing Api:

```
http://support.nbox.live:82/login/

username = admin
password = 123
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking into the concept of `interceptors` with Dio. Also, notice that you're using a new dio instance in both controllers `final _dio = Dio();`. You should initialise `Dio()` once and then use that same instance across the app. https://medium.com/flutter-community/dio-interceptors-in-flutter-17be4214f363

Comment: Apparently your API has more than one method of operation. The flow that you show in the Postman screenshots *isn't using the Bearer token at all*, but works because the server returns 2 cookies in the response to the `/login/` POST and Postman sends them back (automatically) in the `/data/care_api/...` GET. You can certainly get it working using the cookie method if you need, but may be easier to get working using the bearer token method. Do you have any documentation explaining the Bearer token method. (Unfortunately you may have hit a server bug where it doesn't accept lower case headers.)

Comment: you need to add update();  after this line to update your UI  customerDataList.value = res.data['data']['customer_info']; because you are using Getx. one more thing You need to map this API data in the dart model class instead of manually getting data using typecasting.